# Android: how-to save/store destructible terrains (Bitmap's state) in memory when device is in "sleep mode"?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, bitmap, save

I'm coding an Android 4.0+ game where levels are 3200*640px destructible terrains (they are stored as Bitmaps in memory).

When the game/the Activity is interrupted (=> player received a phone call, player hit the "Home" button, device is set in "sleep mode", etc...), I would like to keep/store the game's state (= current shape of the destructible level + sprites' locations) in order to allow the player to continue the level in the very same situation it was before the interruption (just as any serious game does, actually).

Could you enlighten me on the best way(s) to store my game's state (including the Bitmaps' current data!!!) when the game is interrupted ("onPause()/onStop()" calls), please? 
I really have no idea about how the other games do that so nicely!!!

Thank you very much for you help!

ps: I'm asking this question because I made some tests, and it seems the garbage collector reclaims my game's allocated memory when the device is in "sleep mode", and therefore I just can't continue a level when the Activity has been interrupted :( (Bitmaps have been freed => NullPointerException)

Comment: Off the cuff, I would think that the answer is to not have a bitmap be your "system of record" for the state of the terrain. Instead, your model data would be a list of things done to the terrain from its original state (e.g., "this thing at such-and-so coordinates got blow'd up"). You would persist that state in a database or other file. Then, when your game restarts, you simply reapply the visual effects to the bitmap.

Comment: "it seems the garbage collector reclaims my game's allocated memory when the device is in "sleep mode"" -- no, your background process is probably being terminated to free up memory for other processes. This is perfectly normal, and will happen in other cases beyond sleep mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'll see what I can do with recording data into a database, but this may be not quite easy, though... Anyway, when I display the value of "Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())", is it normal that it constantly goes down, reaches some low threshold, and then restarts at its initial value (or so)?

Comment: (continued...) Since I load my sprites and bitmaps only once (at the start of a level), I thought my memory footprint would be pretty constant (and it's not the case, as it constantly goes down (like a fast timer) until reaching a low limit, and then it restarts at a high value, then quickly running down again, then ...). Is it normal? Thank you!

Comment: "Is it normal?" -- since I don't view `freeMemory()` as being a particularly useful figure on the Dalvik VM, I haven't investigated its behavior.